# IE7 page zoom - major errors?

Tags: internet-explorer-7, zooming

I have a problem with a layout im building. Page zoom works in every browser without errors, but in IE7 it does not. Even a little zoom makes the page looks wierd - background colors of elements does not follow the text inside those elements (text floating outside the box) and son and son on - have tried to find a solution, and been debugging a bit, but nothing seems to be working so far.

The previous version of the site i am building, works fine with Page zoom in IE7, so there most be some css setting i am doing/using, that makes it looking wierd. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, the page zoom feature in IE7 is actually a text-resize feature, not a true zoom.

As with IE6, in order to have the layout resize in conjunction with the resize, elements must be sized using a non absolute value such as `em` or `%`. Absolute sizes such as `px` do not resize with the text increase.

Comment: Tried implementering this in my ie7.css "* { font-size: 100% !important }" for debugging purposses, but it still fails - the background color of my boxes does not fill the width as it should for eaxample

Comment: It's not the font size you need to use % on, it's the element width itself.

Comment: Tried this then "* { width: 100% !important; font-size: 100% !important }" but still same error persists?

Answer (score 0):

The ie7 zoom functionnality has some issues. They are listed here and some solutions are described too :

[IE7 problem with zoom and position:relative](http://www.brunildo.org/test/ie7_relzoom2.html)
[IE7 problems with Zoom and inline elements](http://www.brunildo.org/test/ie7_badzoom.html)
[IE7 problem with Zoom and background image on body](http://www.brunildo.org/test/ie7b2_bgi_zoom.html)